# sprintf '+' character does not print

Tags: c++, c, printf

I need to include '+' character inside sprintf format parameter.
But I understand it's a flag specifier. So I can't write it like bellow

```
  sprintf( like_part, "'%%'   +   '%s'  + '%%'" , search_string.c_str() );
```

I've tried to escape it with a '%' character but it didn't worked either.
Any idea ?

```
  sprintf( like_part, "'%%'   %+   '%s'  %+ '%%'" , search_string.c_str() );
```

I've searched another way around this. 
But even the reference does not mention anything about how to escape '+' character.

> > http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

UPDATE:
later I've realized that this bellow code is not working too.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
  char buffer[1024];
  strcpy(buffer,"");
  strcat(buffer,"%");
  strcat(buffer,"");
  strcat(buffer,"%");
  printf(buffer);
  printf("\n");

}
```

The output should be '%%' but only '%';
What is the wrong there? 
Am I hit a bug?

Comment: any particular reason why you are using sprintf instead std::sstream ?

Comment: `+` is not a special character for `s?n?printf`. Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and specify which compiler you're using.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/783096372f411226

Comment: exactly what error are you getting with the first sprintf ?

Comment: Your first attempt is completely right. Just compile and try it.

Comment: Can you describe what it is that isn't working with your first example? It "should" work!

Comment: `  sprintf( like_part, "%% %s %%","");
  printf(like_part);` is also not working.

Comment: As for your latest "is it a bug" -- **no**. You are doing a `printf("%%");` and it appears as `%` on your screen because that is [per design](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Comment: @Jongware In the latest update note that I've used strcpy instead of sprintf.
So it should be "%%" printed isn't it? But it does not seems to appear and I don't know why?

Comment: The way the `%` characters are *inserted* into a string does not matter. You are still doing a `printf(buffer);`.

Comment: However '%' is not a meta-character at all.I don't know why this is happening? This is the strcat implementation. Sorry @Jongware but the behavior does not seems to me oky. But yes problem solved using two instead of one.

Comment: **You are using printf**. Apologies for the bold, but it seems necessary to emphasize this. Please read this link: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Answer (score 4):

The first version should work fine. It only has special powers when part of a formatting specifier, e.g.

```
"My number is %+.0e"
```

Answer (score 3):

You *can* write it like in the first example. It's only a specifier when immediately preceded with a `%` character. In all other cases, it's a standard character. Within a `printf` call, the only special character is the `%` symbol (and `\`, of course, but that's not `printf` specific)